# How do I check if a sprite is at a specific location on Monogame XNA C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, position, xna, monogame

I am making a game and am fairy new to this language and I need to detect if a sprite has reached a certain location for the game to have some sort of response.

something like;

```
if ( /* position of sprite1 == (100,400) */ )
{
    // Do stuff; 
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have an `Vector2` variable that keeps their position stored.

Then, you can use that `Vector2` to compare one position with another.

A possible idea is to use it like this:

```
Vector2 position = new Vector2(0,0);

if (position == new Vector2(100, 400))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

and then in the place where you draw your sprite, you replace the sprite's location with the `position` variable.

Keep in mind though, position checking is very precise, if you miss on one pixel, you won't be triggering the if-statement.
Often, you rather want to do collision checking using `Rectangle`, so you have a whole 'hitbox' to check positions with. Though that depends on the context of your game.